# One click, event called twice

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have developed a mobile application. Most of the functions are inside, but I have some very strange behaviour inside the app on iOs (not tested on android yet).

When I click on an item: the event after the click is called twice. This isn't happening the whole time, but happens now and then. This is a problem for when I try to go to the next slide (he things he should move twice to a next slide), but also when I try to open the gallery for selecting photos, he opens the gallery twice, login for facebook happens twice etc... The strange thing is, that this isn't the whole time the case.

I have normal buttons like

```
 <button ion-button color="black" class="skip-button"
 (click)="nextStep()" [hidden]="lastSlide">Next</button>
```

so I don't think that the coding is wrong (or is it wrong).

I use this version:

```
ionic --version
2.1.18
```

In the beginning of the development I hadn't this issue. I think that I was using an older version of ionic2 then. Is there a way to go back perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried in another device? I mean another iOS device? I had a similar problem but it was caused by the phone and not the app itself.

Comment: @Hiraqui I have it on multiple devices (also the testers of the app has this issue). So I don't think it is related to my device (or it has to do with iOS versions)

Answer (score -1):

I was in the meantime working on another project without having this issue (in that project). My last try was to copy the other project and copy pages and providers from the project with the error. The error is now gone, but still no clue why there was such an error.